# How to read a few columns of elasticsearch by spark?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch-hadoop

In the es cluster, it has a large scale data, we used spark to compute data but in the way of `elasticsearch-hadoop`, followed by https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

We have to read full columns of an index.  Is there anything that help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can set config parameter "es.read.field.include" or "es.read.field.exclude" respectively.  Full details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html).  Example assuming Spark 2 or higher.

```
val sparkSession:SparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("jobName")
  .config("es.nodes", "elastichostc1n1.example.com")
  .config("es.read.field.include", "foo,bar")
  .getOrCreate()
```